# Partitioning a linked list around a given value and keeping the original order

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct _listNode{
    int item;
    struct _listNode* next;
};
typedef struct _listNode ListNode;

void printList(ListNode *head);
void deleteList(ListNode **ptrHead);

void triPartition(ListNode** head, int pivot);

int main()
{
    ListNode *head = NULL, *temp;
    int i = 0;
    int pivot = 0;

    scanf("%d",&pivot);

    while (scanf("%d", &i)){
        if (head == NULL){
            head = (ListNode*) malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = head;
        }
        else{
            temp->next = (ListNode*) malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->item = i;
    }
    temp->next = NULL;


    triPartition(&head, pivot);
    printList(head);
    deleteList(&head);

    return 0;
}

void printList(ListNode *head){
    while(head !=NULL){
        printf("%d ",head->item);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void deleteList(ListNode **ptrHead){
    ListNode *cur = *ptrHead;
    ListNode *temp;
    while (cur!= NULL) {
        temp=cur->next;
        free(cur);
        cur=temp;
    }
    *ptrHead=NULL;
}

void triPartition(ListNode** head, int pivot){
    ListNode *cur = *head;
    ListNode *nextnode = NULL;
    ListNode *pre = NULL;
    ListNode *temp = NULL;

    while (cur != NULL) {
        nextnode = cur->next;
        temp = nextnode;
        printList(head);
        if (cur->item > pivot){
            while (temp->next != NULL){
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = cur;
            cur->next = NULL;
            pre = cur;
            cur = nextnode;
            nextnode = cur->next;
            head = cur;
            temp = NULL;
            printList(head);
        }
        if (cur->item = pivot){
            pre = cur;
            head = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
            nextnode = nextnode->next;
            printList(head);
        }
        if (cur->item < pivot){
            pre->next=nextnode;
            cur->next = pre;
            pre = cur;
            head = cur;
            cur = nextnode;
            nextnode = nextnode->next;
            printList(head);
        }
    }
}
```

Example input

5

8 1 5 5 5 7 2 5 a

Expected output

2 1 5 5 5 5 8 7

im tryna reassign the head to the next node in the original list after moving the first node to the end

but somehow the item in the next node gets changed
and somehow the list gets shorter

i dont get what is wrong w the assigning of the head which results to this.
and i also dont get why i cant use

```
*head = cur
```

Comment: Please do not post text as images. Copy/type it directly into the question as text.

Comment: In `triPartition()` the argument `head` is a `ListNode**` but you treat it like `ListNode*` for instance in the call to `pritnList()`, `head = cur;` etc. `if (cur->item = pivot)` is an assignment but you probably compare `==`.

Comment: Your expected output is not keeping the original order.  It should be `1 2 5 5 5 8 7`, no?  Please update question.

Comment: The `if` statements testing against different pivot conditions looks wrong, it may not be, but normally a single case to be handled per loop iteration.

Comment: Minor suggestion: if you're going to separately typedef your struct, move the typedef before the struct definition. That way inside your struct you can declare: `ListNode *next`.

Comment: It looks suspicious that in your `triPartition` function you have three separate conditional statements. These appear to be meant to only have one execute, but as you're changing `cur` in each, it's possible more than one or all of them will execute. Might be time to employ `else`.

Comment: The output is 2155587 as the 2 is brought to the front of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It was trivial to replace `head` with `*head` in the body of `triPartition()` but that left with a cycle in linked list.  Looked at it for a while but I found it hard to reason about the algorithm because you have 4 variables and the pointers interact.  After looking for a it a while, I figured you can look at the linked list this way:

```
a->        b->     c->
^ *head    ^ left  ^ cur
```

`*head` pointers to the first element of the the list, it may be different than what we were passed in so we do need a double pointer here.  Elements from `*head` till and including `left` are smaller than the pivot.  Elements from `left->next` to `cur` are pivot nodes followed by nodes larger than the pivot.  This implementation reverses the order or pivots, you can fix that after the fact, or maintain a `right` pointer at the boundary between pivot and larger nodes.

I wrote a function `createList()` to create a list as it's much easier to test a non-interactive program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
    int item;
    struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;

ListNode *createList(unsigned n, int *items) {
    ListNode *head = malloc(n * sizeof(*head));
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        head[i].item = items[i];
        head[i].next = i + 1 < n ? &head[i+1] : NULL;
    }
    return head;
}

void printList(ListNode *head){
    for(; head; head = head->next) {
        printf("%d ", head->item);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void triPartition(ListNode **head, int pivot) {
    ListNode *left = NULL;
    for(ListNode *cur = *head; cur->next; ) {
        int op = cur->next->item < pivot ? -1 : cur->next->item == pivot ? 0 : 1;
        if(op <= 0) {
            if(!left) {
                left = cur->next;
                cur->next = cur->next->next;
                left->next = *head;
                *head = left;
                continue;
            }
            ListNode *tmp = left->next;
            left->next = cur->next;
            cur->next = cur->next->next;
            left->next->next = tmp;
            if(op < 0)
                left = left->next;
        } else {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    ListNode *head = createList(8, (int []) {8, 1, 5, 5, 5, 7, 2, 5});
    printList(head);
    triPartition(&head, 5);
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

and here the output of the above program:

```
8 1 5 5 5 7 2 5
1 2 5 5 5 5 8 7
```